# Incompatible appcompat and play-services-vision dependencies between app: compat-v7: 28.0.0 and play-services-vision: 18.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, ide

I am creating an application to detect faces using the firebase classes. However, I am having a compatibility issue between the com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0 and com.google.android.gms: play-services-vision: 18.0.0 dependencies. I have tried several methods to solve this but so far I have not achieved anything that solved. Android studio returns me the following message:

> Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx. * Can not
>   be combined but found IdeMavenCoordinates {myGroupId =
>   'com.android.support', myArtifactId = 'viewpager', myVersion = '28 .0.
>   0 ', myPacking =' aar ', myClassifier =' null '} and
>   IdeMavenCoordinates {myGroupId =' androidx.lifecycle ', myArtifactId
>   =' lifecycle-runtime ', myVersion =' 2.0.0 ', myPacking =' aar ', myClassifier = 'null'} incompatible dependencies less ... (Ctrl + F1)
>   Inspection info: There are some combinations of libraries, or tools
>   and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such
>   incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support
>   libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a lower
>   version than your targetSdkVersion).

Below the image with the description of the problem:
[Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwW1h.png)

Comment: The gsm library requires androidx libraries. You can't use the support libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is happening because you are using the **Support Library** along with the version `18.0.0`of the `play-services-vision` library which already migrated to AndroidX.

You can see [HERE](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) that some libraries migrated to Android X (such as the `play-services-vision`)

So, you are getting this error because your app is using Support Library but `play-services-vision` is already using AndroidX.

In order to fix:

1) Migrate your app to AndroidX (recommended). More info [HERE](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

2) Use an old version of play-services-vision (such as `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0'` for example.)

This second option may fix your issue because `play-services-ads:16.0.0` was still using Support Library as well.